# Automatic navigation of page in WPF using c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, navigation

I want to set my wpf application to navigate to another page **after 3 second** using c#.

Is this possible? If yes then how?

Comment: You could create a new thread, then use Thread.Sleep to wait for 3 seconds in that new thread, and then call some logic to go to another Page within Dispatcher.Invoke, which will call back into your UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either use a **Timer** and set the **Tick** to 3000 which would a fire a method, changing the page. Or you could start a new **Thread**, put a **thread.sleep(3000)** then call the page change. If you do the second method, you need to use **Dispatcher.Invoke** as you are not on the main UI thread.